# azure node js getting status code 502.3 for post and get method

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, azure

I am continuously getting 502 error for my website, It will be developed in angular and node js database is MongoDB and hosted in azure windows. I have added an error log. Kindly check anyone given the solution for this error. stuck the last two weeks for this issue.

```
<failedRequest url="https://mywebsite/api/v1/task/notification/count/"
               siteId="2"
               appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
               processId="2680"
               verb="GET"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{800007B1-0002-D600-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="502.3"
               triggerStatusCode="502.3"
               timeTaken="5031"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
```

Comment: 502.3 errors can be multiple reasons: timeout, high cpu usage, network issues

Comment: Sometimes I'm getting 502.2, 502.5 on my website and getting error in socket.io.

Comment: go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics , then check Availability and Performance -> Health Check

Comment: 1. It throws error as "Error Message SyntaxError: Unexpected token".
2. Handshake Timeout is occurred due to Session handling not properly handled / Incoming request gets rejected in header level.
3.he Incoming request gets rejected in header level basic authentication.  These errors i am getting